# How to get sum of list which is inside another list?

Tags: lambda, prolog, swi-prolog

I have a list which consists number of lists. I would like to get sum of those lists into another list.

> full_list([[12,13,14],[5,7,9],[1,12,72]]). %this is my original list

I would like to get an output like below,
L=[39,21,85].

Someone please explain me how to do this using prolog.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

there is [sum_list](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=sum_list/2)/2, a ready to use builtin:

```
full_list(I, L) :-
    maplist(sum_list, I, L).
```

test:

```
?- full_list([[12,13,14],[5,7,9],[1,12,72]], L).
L = [39, 21, 85].
```

Comment: just discrovered sim_list predicate, and, more powerfull maplist! Thanks

Answer (score 2):

A functionnal design, working with SWI-Prolog

```
:- use_module(library(lambda)).

sum_list(L, R) :-
    maplist(\X^foldl(\T^U^V^(V is T+U), X, 0), L, R).
```

lambda.pl can be found here : http://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/ulrich/Prolog-inedit/lambda.pl

Answer (score 0):

Use a list sum predicate like this :

```
listSum(nil,N,N);
listSum([H|Tail],N,Res) :- Acc is N+H, listSum(Tail,Acc,Res)


sumofSubLists([L1,L2,L3],[R1,R2,R3]):-
     listSum(L1,0,R1),
     listSum(L2,0,R2),
     listSum(L3,0,R3)
```

Calling

```
sumofSubLists([[12,13,14],[5,7,9],[1,12,72]], ResultList)
```

should give the result. 
This can be done more efficiently ...
Hope it helps

---

Well if you want to do it with any number of list you need to define some new predicates :

AddElement to add a new element to a list:

```
   addElement(X,[],[X]); 
   addElement(X,L,[X|L]);
```

Another one to append lists:

```
  append([],X,X);
  append([T|Q1],X,[T|Q2]) :- append(Q1,X,Q2);
```

And a recursive one to work on lists:

```
 sumSubListsRec(nil,AccList,ResultList):- ResultList = AccList;
 sumSubListsRec([HeadList| Tail], AccList,ResultList) :-
              listSum(HeadList,0,Tmp),
              append(AccList,[Tmp],T),
              sumSubListsRec(Tail,T,ResultList);
```

Now you can call it with any number of lists.

Comment: `append/3` is built-in. You never used `addElement/3` after defining it.